# Group By varbinary (MAX) or varchar (MAX) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In SQL Server 2008 R2 Books Online, it implies the maximum column size of the grouping columns is 8060 bytes.

> "For GROUP BY clauses that do not contain CUBE or ROLLUP, the number of group_by_expression items is limited by the GROUP BY column sizes, the aggregated columns, and the aggregate values involved in the query. This limit originates from the limit of 8,060 bytes on the intermediate worktable that is needed to hold intermediate query results."

But you **can** group by a varbinary (max) column:

```
create table dbo.T(
  name varchar(100),
  info varbinary(max)
);
insert into dbo.T values ('aardvark', Convert(varbinary(max),Replicate(Convert(varchar(max),'A'),100000)))
select info, count(*) from T group by info;
```

The above works fine in SQL Server 2008 R2, and presumably later versions. Have I misread the Books Online? Does anyone know if grouping by large object types is allowed? I have also Googled this with no result.

Comment: This limit may not be enforced or checked explicitly. Try writing >8k bytes in such columns and running your code.

Comment: @Stoleg And it will still work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are much more likely to encounter this issue with fixed width datatypes as they are always stored in row. Variable length types can be stored out of row with a pointer to the actual value.

```
CREATE TABLE #T
  (
     C CHAR(4027) DEFAULT REPLICATE('A', 4027)
  );

INSERT INTO #T
DEFAULT VALUES;

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   #T T1
       CROSS JOIN #T T2
GROUP  BY T1.C,
          T2.C
```

> The query processor could not produce a query plan because a worktable
>   is required, and its minimum row size exceeds the maximum allowable of
>   8060 bytes. A typical reason why a worktable is required is a GROUP BY
>   or ORDER BY clause in the query. If the query has a GROUP BY or ORDER
>   BY clause, consider reducing the number and/or size of the fields in
>   the clause. Consider using prefix (LEFT()) or hash (CHECKSUM()) of
>   fields for grouping or prefix for ordering. Note however that this
>   will change the behavior of the query.

But the following succeeds.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   #T T1
       CROSS JOIN #T T2
GROUP  BY CAST(T1.C AS VARCHAR(4027)),
          CAST(T2.C AS VARCHAR(4027))
```

You can group by up to 308 varchar(max) columns - with only 26 bytes per column stored in row ([pointer to the value and other overhead](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2007/07/16/geek-city-maximum-number-of-row-overflow-columns.aspx)).

The below fails with

> Cannot create a row of size 8078 which is greater than the allowable
>   maximum row size of 8060.

But remove any of the `GROUP BY` columns and it will succeed as 8078-26 is less than 8060.

NB: Each individual column has values that consume 10,000 bytes but this is stored off row and not relevant to the above calculation.

```
drop TABLE #T

GO

CREATE TABLE #T
(
 C0 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C1 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C2 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C3 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C4 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C5 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C6 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C7 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C8 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C9 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C10 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C11 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C12 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C13 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C14 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C15 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C16 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C17 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C18 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C19 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C20 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C21 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C22 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C23 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C24 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C25 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C26 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C27 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C28 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C29 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C30 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C31 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C32 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C33 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C34 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C35 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C36 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C37 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C38 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C39 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C40 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C41 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C42 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C43 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C44 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C45 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C46 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C47 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C48 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C49 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C50 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C51 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C52 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C53 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C54 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C55 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C56 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C57 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C58 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C59 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C60 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C61 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C62 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C63 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C64 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C65 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C66 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C67 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C68 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C69 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C70 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C71 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C72 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C73 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C74 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C75 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C76 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C77 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C78 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C79 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C80 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C81 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C82 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C83 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C84 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C85 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C86 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C87 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C88 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C89 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C90 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C91 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C92 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C93 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C94 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C95 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C96 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C97 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C98 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
,C99 VARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000)
)


INSERT INTO #T DEFAULT VALUES


SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM #T T1,
     #T T2,
     #T T3,
     #T T4
GROUP BY 
 T1.C0
,T1.C1
,T1.C2
,T1.C3
,T1.C4
,T1.C5
,T1.C6
,T1.C7
,T1.C8
,T1.C9
,T1.C10
,T1.C11
,T1.C12
,T1.C13
,T1.C14
,T1.C15
,T1.C16
,T1.C17
,T1.C18
,T1.C19
,T1.C20
,T1.C21
,T1.C22
,T1.C23
,T1.C24
,T1.C25
,T1.C26
,T1.C27
,T1.C28
,T1.C29
,T1.C30
,T1.C31
,T1.C32
,T1.C33
,T1.C34
,T1.C35
,T1.C36
,T1.C37
,T1.C38
,T1.C39
,T1.C40
,T1.C41
,T1.C42
,T1.C43
,T1.C44
,T1.C45
,T1.C46
,T1.C47
,T1.C48
,T1.C49
,T1.C50
,T1.C51
,T1.C52
,T1.C53
,T1.C54
,T1.C55
,T1.C56
,T1.C57
,T1.C58
,T1.C59
,T1.C60
,T1.C61
,T1.C62
,T1.C63
,T1.C64
,T1.C65
,T1.C66
,T1.C67
,T1.C68
,T1.C69
,T1.C70
,T1.C71
,T1.C72
,T1.C73
,T1.C74
,T1.C75
,T1.C76
,T1.C77
,T1.C78
,T1.C79
,T1.C80
,T1.C81
,T1.C82
,T1.C83
,T1.C84
,T1.C85
,T1.C86
,T1.C87
,T1.C88
,T1.C89
,T1.C90
,T1.C91
,T1.C92
,T1.C93
,T1.C94
,T1.C95
,T1.C96
,T1.C97
,T1.C98
,T1.C99

,T2.C0
,T2.C1
,T2.C2
,T2.C3
,T2.C4
,T2.C5
,T2.C6
,T2.C7
,T2.C8
,T2.C9
,T2.C10
,T2.C11
,T2.C12
,T2.C13
,T2.C14
,T2.C15
,T2.C16
,T2.C17
,T2.C18
,T2.C19
,T2.C20
,T2.C21
,T2.C22
,T2.C23
,T2.C24
,T2.C25
,T2.C26
,T2.C27
,T2.C28
,T2.C29
,T2.C30
,T2.C31
,T2.C32
,T2.C33
,T2.C34
,T2.C35
,T2.C36
,T2.C37
,T2.C38
,T2.C39
,T2.C40
,T2.C41
,T2.C42
,T2.C43
,T2.C44
,T2.C45
,T2.C46
,T2.C47
,T2.C48
,T2.C49
,T2.C50
,T2.C51
,T2.C52
,T2.C53
,T2.C54
,T2.C55
,T2.C56
,T2.C57
,T2.C58
,T2.C59
,T2.C60
,T2.C61
,T2.C62
,T2.C63
,T2.C64
,T2.C65
,T2.C66
,T2.C67
,T2.C68
,T2.C69
,T2.C70
,T2.C71
,T2.C72
,T2.C73
,T2.C74
,T2.C75
,T2.C76
,T2.C77
,T2.C78
,T2.C79
,T2.C80
,T2.C81
,T2.C82
,T2.C83
,T2.C84
,T2.C85
,T2.C86
,T2.C87
,T2.C88
,T2.C89
,T2.C90
,T2.C91
,T2.C92
,T2.C93
,T2.C94
,T2.C95
,T2.C96
,T2.C97
,T2.C98
,T2.C99


,T3.C0
,T3.C1
,T3.C2
,T3.C3
,T3.C4
,T3.C5
,T3.C6
,T3.C7
,T3.C8
,T3.C9
,T3.C10
,T3.C11
,T3.C12
,T3.C13
,T3.C14
,T3.C15
,T3.C16
,T3.C17
,T3.C18
,T3.C19
,T3.C20
,T3.C21
,T3.C22
,T3.C23
,T3.C24
,T3.C25
,T3.C26
,T3.C27
,T3.C28
,T3.C29
,T3.C30
,T3.C31
,T3.C32
,T3.C33
,T3.C34
,T3.C35
,T3.C36
,T3.C37
,T3.C38
,T3.C39
,T3.C40
,T3.C41
,T3.C42
,T3.C43
,T3.C44
,T3.C45
,T3.C46
,T3.C47
,T3.C48
,T3.C49
,T3.C50
,T3.C51
,T3.C52
,T3.C53
,T3.C54
,T3.C55
,T3.C56
,T3.C57
,T3.C58
,T3.C59
,T3.C60
,T3.C61
,T3.C62
,T3.C63
,T3.C64
,T3.C65
,T3.C66
,T3.C67
,T3.C68
,T3.C69
,T3.C70
,T3.C71
,T3.C72
,T3.C73
,T3.C74
,T3.C75
,T3.C76
,T3.C77
,T3.C78
,T3.C79
,T3.C80
,T3.C81
,T3.C82
,T3.C83
,T3.C84
,T3.C85
,T3.C86
,T3.C87
,T3.C88
,T3.C89
,T3.C90
,T3.C91
,T3.C92
,T3.C93
,T3.C94
,T3.C95
,T3.C96
,T3.C97
,T3.C98
,T3.C99
,T4.C0
,T4.C1
,T4.C2
,T4.C3
,T4.C4
,T4.C5
,T4.C6
,T4.C7
,T4.C8
```

Comment: Then is it correct to say, that as varchar(max) and varbinary(max) are stored out-of-row, they only use up the GROUP BY row size limit to the extent of the size of their pointers, not the actual data? That seems to be what is happening.